# Is the "S Pen remote SDK" a replacement for the "S Pen SDK"?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk, stylus-pen

In my KitKat-era Android app I used the S Pen SDK v. 2.3 by adding `libspen23.jar` to `<proj>/libs/`.

Meanwhile (2013 -> 2020), Samsung seems to have adopted a new name. The `Spen SDK` is no longer offered. Samsung offers instead an [S Pen Remote SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-spen-remote/s-pen-remote-sdk.html), which includes `spenremote-v1.0.X.jar` and `sdk-v1.0.0.jar`.

***Is the "S Pen remote SDK" a replacement for the "S Pen SDK"?***

For reference, the S Pen SDK v. 2.3 was sizeable.

```
/Users/calaf/prj/proj/libs:
total used in directory 27345 available 478.2 GiB
drwxr-xr-x  4 calaf  staff      128 Mar 10 07:52 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 calaf  staff      256 Dec 23 08:28 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 calaf  staff   648327 Aug 21 17:00 android-support-v4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 calaf  staff  4292169 Aug 21 17:00 libspen23.jar
```

Whereas the S Pen Remote v. 1.0.1 is quite tiny.

```
/Users/calaf/Downloads/SpenRemoteSDK_v1:
total used in directory 52 available 478.2 GiB
drwxr-xr-x@   4 calaf  staff    128 Dec 26 22:29 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 280 calaf  staff  15744 Dec 26 22:29 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 calaf  staff   2008 Nov 30  2016 sdk-v1.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r--@   1 calaf  staff  23740 Aug 30  2019 spenremote-v1.0.1.jar
```

Comment: I believe that `S Pen Remote` is for the side button and orientation of the stylus. Modern Android has support for stylus: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/stylus

Comment: I was going to develop an app using Samsung S Pen SDK, and now only remote is being offered. I about to decide not to develop this app for Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know Spen Remote Sdk is a replacement for spen sdk, spen sdk is for old android versions, deprecated, kind of, Spen remote sdk is, for newer android versions,  as a repacement, for remote actions, newer devices, and more, kind of like air actions in settings, or etc.